# Jenkins build fails at compile with "unmappable character for encoding ASCII"

Tags: eclipse, svn, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a .java file that contains UTF-8 characters. So I told eclipse to use UTF-8 encoding for its .java files. When trying to build it via Jenkins it fails however with

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

.../... unmappable character for encoding ASCII
```

When browsing to my svn repository I notice that the special characters are encoded using weird signs. Is there a way to get those characters into my repository correctly? Do I have to tell my svn repository to use UTF-8 somehow. Or my subclipse plugin..?

**Edit**

Updated my question to help others locate the problem.

Comment: After reading your question and the description of the case I still don't understand what's the problem. Could you please specify the steps you perform as well as the **unexpected** results you get?

Comment: tried to provide some key points, hope this helps to understand my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Set svn:mime-type to text/plain;charset=UTF-8 ,  eclipse team> set property > change value > commit
- set file content encoding to utf-8 as you did
- in pom.xml on compilation plugin set Encoding to utf-8:
- http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning

Comment: Thanks for your answer, found the solution but you had it too: set compiler plugin encoding.. Will update my question.

Comment: @Pete: It's better to post your solution as an answer rather than editing it into the question.

Answer (score 15):

As discovered correctly by Philippe Bossu it wasn't an issue with svn or eclipse after all but a **maven setting**. No idea, why it built locally but appearently you have to set the **maven compiler plugin** encoding:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```